# No instance of overloaded function for getline

Tags: c++, string, iostream

I want to read `wstring` from a txt file.
   I store the file's name in a variable called `SourceFileName` and it is `wstring` varaible. In the txt file, it has the following strings:

```
112:abc
221:ghj
....
```

Now I want to read these numbers and its corresponding strings from the txt file into wstring strings, but when I was trying to do that, VS notifies me that no instance of overloaded function for std::getline macthes argument list.

```
std::wifstream map;
map.open(SourceFileName.c_str());

std::wstring fileID;
std::wstring fileName;

std::getline(map, fileID, L":");//error happens here.
```

How to fix it?
I also tried `std::getline(map, fileID, ":");`, doesn't work too.
[image]

Comment: What is the exact error? The devil is in the details.

Comment: Did the compiler not suggest any candidates for the overload?

Comment: `std::getline(map, fileID, L':');`  The delimiter is a character, not a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no overload of `std::getline` that would accept a string literal as the third argument. Both overloads that have it require the delimiter to be a character:

```
std::getline(map, fileID, L':');
```

Hint: When the compiler does not find a matching overload, it helps to take a look at what type of arguments the overloads do accept.